# accessing python object member that is a reserved keyword

Tags: python

I'm using OptionParser to get some command line options for a script.  I have the following in my script:

```
parser.add_option("--pass", help="password used for authentication")
(options, args) = parser.parse_args()
```

OptionParser takes all the options and puts them as named members on an object.  Thus, to access the option in 'pass' I'd have to reference options.pass.  This throws an exception, as pass is a reserved keyword (I assume... I'm a python n00b).

How would I access this member to get at the data?  I know I could change the name of the option, but I'm curious how to do this without changing the name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `getattr()` function to retrieve it by name: `getattr(options, 'pass')`.  When accessing attributes this way you have fewer restrictions on how they can be named, like in this case you can use a keyword.

Comment: Wow. Sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: @Elazar: What does? That you can use a keyword for an attribute name? Remember, essentially attributes are just a dictionary anyway, so it shouldn't be surprising that they can have fairly arbitrary names -- it's just that syntactically they can't be expressed in the dot notation.

Comment: The fact that an object can have an attribute that can't be accessed using the dot notation (even from its own methods) sounds like a bug. There's just no way it is an intentional "feature". What's wrong with `x.pass` ? If you are not allowing this, you should add an explicit check to the dictionary. Oh, is it too expensive? so do allow it. Change the grammar, if needed.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `getattr()` function to retrieve it: `getattr(options, 'pass')`

However, it would be better not to use reserved keywords as members.  You can keep the `--pass` option but save it as `password` with this:

```
parser.add_option("--pass", help="password used for authentication", dest='password')
```

Then, `options.password` isn't a problem.